# show hidden div in overlay works but no style

Tags: jquery, css

First off I'm self taught.

I'm using fancybox to show a hidden `div` and it works fine.
My problem is I cannot get it in my head how to call the stylesheet for the hidden `div`.

Can someone tell me the proper way to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".fancybox").fancybox({padding : 0, openEffect  : 'elastic'});       
   });
</script>
```

My hidden div:

```
<div id="contact" class="contact item">
```

Comment: What isn't working here?

Comment: just write your styles for `#contact` as for any other element on the page

Comment: What I'm saying is the content of the div shows in fancybox but without any style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could style the div using a stylesheet, e.g.

**site.css** (or any stylesheet, not sure what yours is called)

```
.contact { padding: 0px; }
```

Or alternatively if you want to use Javascript to set the style, do it anytime before or after you apply fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#contact").css("padding", "0px");
      $(".fancybox").fancybox({openEffect  : 'elastic'});
   });
</script>
```

Note that, if you're showing the contents of your example div, fancybox takes the contents of the hidden div and displays it, not the outer div itself, which would break your css selectors. In this case, a better example would be:

```
<style type="text/css">
.contact { border: 1px solid pink; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#fancyBoxContents").fancybox();
   });
</script>

<div id="fancyBoxContents"><div class="contact">will be displayed</div></div>
```

Comment: Jed Watson I added a div around the hidden div as you indicated but it still does not pick up the style. This is driving me crazy. I'm just not seeing something.

Comment: Could you put the entire code for the example of what's not working in a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net)? I'll take a look and see if I can work out what you're missing.

Comment: Jed Watson after going from fancybox to facebox to jquery dialog box and coming up with the same results I found my problem. I did not realize after adding the outer wrapper you must change your style sheet for the inner div. Anyway all working now and I've learned alot. Thanks for your time and help it got me going in the right direction. I will mark it closed.